# Print content in a popup with CSS

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to print the contents of a fancybox (it's like a lightbox) in a popup and am having problems.  The cause is the css is not loaded when I directly call print();

Here is my code:

```
function printFancy() {
    var $fancycontent = $("div.fancybox-overlay .fancybox-inner").clone();
    $fancycontent.find(".dontprint").remove();


    var title = $fancycontent .find(".title");
    var base = $("base").attr("href");

    var mywindow = window.open('', 'print', 'height='+$(window).height()+',width='+$(window).width());
    mywindow.document.write('<html><head><title>'+title.html()+'</title>');
    mywindow.document.write('<base href="'+base+'">');

    $("link[rel=stylesheet]").each(function() {
        if($(this).attr("href").indexOf("neededstyles")!=-1) {
            var stylesheet=$(this).attr("href");
            mywindow.document.write('<link rel="stylesheet" href="'+stylesheet+'" type="text/css" />');
        }

    });
//this dont get fired.
    mywindow.document.write('</head><body onload="window.print()">');
    mywindow.document.write($fancycontent.html());
    mywindow.document.write('</body></html>');

//this dont get fired.
    mywindow.onload = function() {
        console.log("onload to print");
    };
    //this get fired but the CSS is not loaded
    jQuery(mywindow.document).ready(function() {
        console.log("ready to print");
        // mywindow.print();
        // mywindow.close();
    });


}
```

As you can see I've tried different possibilities and none of them work. What I really don't understand why the `mywindow.onload` and the body onload don't get fired at all.

Is there a mistake in my understanding? Why does it not work? Or is there another, better way to print only the content of the fancybox (or any other div)?

For now I am using:

```
setTimeout(function(){mywindow.print();mywindow.close()},1000);
```

which works. Not sure if it will work if someone has a really slow connection.

Edit: In Firefox the printdialog only appears when I close the popup.  There must be a better solution.

Comment: My suggestion: keep all html in a variable and do one call `mywindow.document.write(allHtmlForPrint);`

Comment: @JohnnyJS i tried that. Its the same. still don't know why body onload dont work. I copied the hole html into a new file and when I open it the body onload works.